# Acessing image folder outside wamp folder

Tags: php, root

i have my web folder in c:/wamp/www/ which is the default webroot for wamp. Then i have a folder image in c:/image/ that contains images been processed by another application which i wont like to relocate. I want to be able to load up an image with its file name from c:/image/

e.g. img src = "c:/image/FA12.jpg"

within my PHP scripts. I really Need Help on this Please. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read a file into php use "c:\image\FA12.jpg". You may also create a link "file://c\image\FA12.jpg". There's no way to create a relative path, since it is outside root dir.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it is better to create a folder of your images under your localhost or server ('var/www/images') to have a proper relative URL to that images.

Url's like c:\image\fa12.jpg can create problems when you make your product online. Other wise you can do provide static urls as kirilloid suggest or you can copy that images to some proper folder in your localhost sever with use of php function "copy" and use that folder as a reference. avoid static url's if possible.:)

as i have linux system now i tested below code locally. create one file test.php under /www and put below code in it and run file in browser. see if this can be your solution

```
<?php $link  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$domain = strstr($link, '/www');
echo $domain;//this will output /www

$root = strstr($link, '/www', true); 
echo "<br>".$root;//this will output /var
?>
```

You can try this by putting "/wamp/www" instead of "/www" in above code and you will get c:/ (perhaps) in $root and then appeng folder name images and path accordingly to $root.

May this will help you